# No Video output when attempting to run Facade

Tags: pc, technical-issues, facade

I downloaded Facade from the official website. After installing it, I tried to play it, but after the initial loading screen, the game vanished into just the outline of the window it was in. The sound works fine, and the hand still appears where the mouse is, and I can type responses, but there is no visual at all. I tried adjusting my computer to the resolution it mentions on the website but my computer's resolution won't go low enough. Is there a way to fix this or is the game not compatible with my pc?

Device Manager lists my graphics card as:

> Mobile Intel (R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM1.1)

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Most importantly, your graphics card and operating system will be very helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

The [official site](http://www.interactivestory.net/help/#antialiasing) recommends this, in case of a crash after loading screen:

> **Q: When I launch Façade I never get past the loading screen, or past
>   the initial fade up at the front door.**
>
> On Windows, what could be happening is that your videocard settings
>   for antialiasing and anisotropic filtering are set such that they are
>   incompatible with Façade's unusual rendering style. A solution that
>   may allow Façade to run is to set these features to "application
>   controlled". (We believe the "application controlled" setting will
>   still allow these features to be active when you play other games, it
>   just gives each application the option to use them or not.)
>
> To try this, open the Control Panel called "Display", go to the
>   "Settings" tab, click "Advanced", and then search for a dialog that
>   may be called something like "Performance & Quality Settings", to find
>   the settings for "Antialiasing" and possibly "Anisotropic Filtering",
>   if your videocard supports that. Change these settings to "application
>   controlled", and close the control panel. Then try running Façade
>   again.

You could give this a try.