# Help me fix façade!

Tags: windows-7, facade

I have windows 7, and I recently downloaded Façade. When it was finished downloading, I opened it up and there were (seemingly) no problems. The red curtain for loading came, then the black screen while you hear Trips voice mail. Then they show you a picture of Grace and Trip in their apartment. Only, on my computer they don't look right. They don't have colored eyes. Just plain white. The graphics are crappier than usual. Then the menu where you pick your name would pop up, right? On my computer, it's a black screen. There's a gray box, (I'm assuming this is where the name selection takes place), but it's just black and gray. Nothing else. What am I supposed to do to fix this? Can Façade run on windows 7?

Comment: Can you list your graphics card?

Comment: I don't know what that is.. D:

Comment: To find the name of your graphics card (which is what makes graphics happen): Click the Windows menu, find the "Computer" option on the right side and **right** click on it to bring up a popup menu, pick "properties" from the popup menu. This will show you basic system info. In the list at left should be "Device Manager". Click that. (If a window comes up saying something about accounts, click OK. It's not important here.) Then find "Display adapters" and click the triangle beside it to rotate it pointing down. Now you should see the name of your graphics card.

Comment: This is exactly what it said: 
Mobile Intel (R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM1.1)

Comment: is this going to help me fix the game? :D you'd seriously be my best friend if you fixed it.

Comment: That will help *us* diagnose the problem.

Comment: Are you the same user as the one who posted [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107500/facade-wont-work)? If you are, we'd like to concentrate everything in one place.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate of anything. i accidentally asked this question again, because it told me my question got deleted. but this all happened to me, i didn't duplicate this from anyone.

Comment: @tryingnottobreakstuff It's not that you duplicated this from anyone, it's that someone's already asked this question, and we don't allow duplicate questions.  Try what the answers on the other question state, and see if that works.

Comment: OKAY. I tried what the other one told me, and I didn't have the options that it suggested on my computer. There wasn't a settings tab on my display, or anything after else. Care to help me?